# Draw polygons around a set of points and create clusters in Python

Tags: polygon, geopandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing `Lat`, `Long` coordinates. How do I draw non-overlapping polygons around a cluster of points and aggregate the geometries in a GeoPandas DataFrame. Below is sample code to work with:

Below is sample code to work with:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import geopandas as gpd 

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'yr': [2018, 2017, 2018, 2016], 'id': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'v': [10, 12, 8, 10], 'lat': [32.7418248, 32.8340583, 32.8340583, 32.7471895], 'lon':[-97.524066, -97.0805484, -97.0805484, -96.9400779] }) 

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['lon'], df['lat'])) 

# set crs for buffer calculations 
df.set_crs("ESRI:102003", inplace=True)
```

The Polygons can be of any shape, however, must include a minimum of 5 points. I tried creating a buffer around the points but circle is not the ideal solution. I am looking for a way to draw a more flexible polygon. This polygon representation will be added as a new column to the pandas DataFrame containing the points.

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html

[image]

Comment: You need to `df = df.set_crs(4326)` before `df.to_crs("ESRI:102003", inplace=True)`

Answer (score 4):

Group the points using cluster dbscan, convex hull the groups.

This does not guarantee they dont overlap, you will have to manually adjust the parameters until they dont.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import pandas as pd
from shapely.ops import unary_union

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/bs_sample.shp')

df['xcoord'] = df.geometry.x
df['ycoord'] = df.geometry.y

#Cluster nearby points together
coords = df[['xcoord','ycoord']].values #Create a numpy array
db = DBSCAN(eps=1200, min_samples=5).fit(coords) #Cluster the points. eps is max distance to cluster points together
cluster_labels = pd.Series(db.labels_).rename('cluster') #Extract cluster labels
df = pd.concat([df, cluster_labels], axis=1) #Add them to the points

#df.cluster.unique()
#array([-1,  0,  1,  4,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8]) #points without cluster get -1

#Adjust eps and plot until it looks as good as possible
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=df['xcoord'], y=df['ycoord'], c=df['cluster'], marker='.', cmap='tab10')

#Create convex hulls from each cluster
hulls = [] #A list to hold clusterids and convex hull geometries
for clusterid, frame in df.loc[df['cluster']!=-1].groupby('cluster'): #For each cluster group except -1
    geom = unary_union(frame.geometry.tolist()).convex_hull #Create one multipoint and convex hull it
    hulls.append([clusterid, geom])
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=hulls, columns=['cluster','geometry'])
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df2, geometry=df2['geometry'], crs=df.crs)

df2.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/bs_sample_cluster.shp')
```

[image]